# Disable ESLint / CSSLint / Javascript validation / CSS validation for one project in VS 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

Working on a project with old javascript compatible only for IE6 (sorry ...), I would like to Disable ESLint / CSSLint / Javascript validation / CSS validation for this project only in VS 2017.

I'm aware of the Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> ESlint -> Enable EsLint, unfortunately this option disables ESLint for every project : I would like to have ESLint enable for new web projects.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

A bit late so I think you allready found it. Maybe it helps someone else.

You can turn off CssLint in Tools\Options\Text Editor\CSS\CssLint. There you have the option to disable CSS Lint.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works for a complete disable of cssLint. My first objective was to disable lint for one project only